# bundler installs gem from GitHub under "bundler" directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

Because of problems with compass-rails, I have added (following others' advice) the following to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'compass-rails', git: 'https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails', branch: 'master'
```

This works, but compass-rails gets installed under:

```
.../ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/compass-rails-a1c890628d61
```

It is the only gem in that directory.  All other gems are under:

```
.../ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems
```

The result is that "gem list" does not list compass-rails, and when my rails app tries to "require" compass-rails, the gem is not found.  Is there some way to get compass-rails installed in the standard location when installed from a GitHub URL?  Failing that, is there some way to get my application to find gems in the weird directory bundler is putting compass-rails?

Comment: This is entirely normal.

Comment: "Normal" as in "most people experience these problems"? :-)

Comment: As in that is where git gems are installed.

Comment: The problem is that there seem to be two places now.  One is gems/2.2.0/gems, which I was familiar with, and the other is gems/2.2.0/bundler/2.2.0/gems.  Note the word "bundler" in the path.  Only the compass-rails gem is being put there.

Comment: That is just how gems installed through git work